# How to identify a long-running query in the SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We are facing a long-running query in our production database. We tried to run a query to identify the long-running sessions. We also tried to run a query to identify which stored procedure runs long. Afterwards, the result that was return has no record. Meaning, there is no such stored procedure that runs long.

Query to identify the long-running query session:

```
SELECT 
    sqltext.TEXT,
    req.session_id,
    req.status,
    req.command,
    req.cpu_time,
    req.total_elapsed_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE
    sqltext.[Text] NOT LIKE '--''check%'
ORDER BY 
    req.cpu_time DESC
```

This is the snippet of the long-running session:

```
(@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 int)SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[LogType] AS [LogType], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
    FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (7 =  CAST( [Extent1].[LogType] AS int)) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[LogType] AS int) IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[CreatedDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[CreatedDate] <= @p__linq__1) AND ((([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[UserId] IS NULL OR @p__linq__2 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[UserId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
```

We tried this query to identify the long-running stored procedure:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%FROM \[dbo\].\[Logs\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

We need some help on how to identify a long running query instead of checking the stored procedure.

Comment: I would recommend [`sp_whoisactive` - Adam Machanic](http://whoisactive.com) with some guidance on how to use it here:
[How to Use sp_WhoIsActive to Find Slow SQL Server Queries - Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Will try it right a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your long-running session query suggests it is a parameterized query generated from Entity Framework rather than a statement in a stored procedure. Consequently, if you find a proc with similar query text, it is only by coincidence and not the culprit.

I suggest you retrieve the query plan using [sys.dm_exec_query_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-plan-transact-sql). It may be additional indexes are needed on the log table for columns specified in the `WHERE` clause. Also, the `CAST( [Extent1].[LogType] AS int))` may be a problem as that is a non-sargable expression.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thank you for this. I have tried to retrieve our execution query plan for this specific query and it seems that the load of process from the log table is too high since this is not indexed. It's kind of weird since we have tried to check our codes and there is no EF query that selects a statement from the log table.

Comment: @jololandayan, it seems there must be an EF query somewhere in the code that generates this query. If LogType maps to an enum, maybe searching for references to the type 7 value will help find it.